# Custom theme admin login Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, admin, drupal-themes

I have a problem using Drupal 7 admin login in my custom theme. After creating a custom theme when I try to submit the login form, I receive the following error:

*"Access denied You are not authorized to access this page."*

When I revert back to a default theme (eg. Bartik), everything works fine again.

After reading a lot of solutions, I can't seem to find the right one for me. Any ideas?

EDIT:
The problem seems to be the *"drupal_render(drupal_get_form('search_block_form'))"* in my page.tpl.php. For my theme i need a form markup without any container, so i used this function to render the form. The solution for me was to change it like:

```
$form_array= drupal_get_form("user_login"); 
$form = drupal_render($form_array);
echo $form;
```

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at this:
**your-drupal-parh/user** -if this link takes to the login form, then you just need to customize the login form.

If it doesn't help, try create a login.

Update **templete.php**

```
function themename_theme() {
  $items = array();
  $items['user_login'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-login',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
       'themename_preprocess_user_login'
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}

function themename_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
  $vars['intro_text'] = t('Custom login form');
}
```

`themename` is the name of your theme.
`path` points to the path where the *user-login.tpl.php* file exists in your theme directory[here `drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename') . '/templates'` means that the *user-login.tpl.php* file is in the theme's template directory].

Code for ***user-login.tpl.php***:

```
<p><?php print render($intro_text); ?></p>
<div class="redha-user-login-form-wrapper">
  <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
</div>
```

Clear cache and see what happens.